# Unable to read huge CSV file using sep="," in R

Tags: r, csv, bigdata

I am trying to read a huge CSV file(about 35 GB) in R.

I am using `LaF` package for this.

Now in the csv files, all the variables and observations are separated by ",". Adding a snap of this. [image]

If I am apply to a similar looking data

```
df = rbind("varA,varB,varC","Id1,0,23","Id2,1,34","Id3,2,145")

write.table(df,file="data1.csv",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE)

huge_file <- 'data1.csv'
#First detect a data model for your file:
model <- detect_dm_csv(huge_file,header=TRUE,sep=",",fill=TRUE) #1
#model
df.laf <- laf_open(model)
df_read
#  varA.varB.varC
#1       Id1,0,23
#2       Id2,1,34
#3      Id3,2,145
```

I can't figure out how to separate the variables and the observations.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: your strings are quoted so they are interpreted as one value, use `write.table(..., quote = FALSE)` you can see in how excel displays the data that each line is quoted and put in a single column

Comment: Well the 33 GB dataset was given to me. I haven't created it. So is there anyway I can implement this while trying to read the data?

Comment: `read.table(..., quote = '')` would work and `detect_dm_csv` passes arguments to `read.table`, however `be careful with using these as some of these arguments are not supported by laf_open_csv` and adding `quote = ''` to `laf_open_csv` doesnt work

Comment: I'd be inclined to try `fread(...)` in the `data.table` package. but in any event you should be able to open the file in Notepad++, then save say the first 1000 rows and provide a link to that in the question.

Comment: `write.table` uses space separators by default. So your `"data1.csv"` is space-separated, not comma separated. You can verify by looking at your sample file.

Comment: @jlhoward trying to open a 35GB file in Notepad++ sounds like a way to hang up your computer for a while. Better move would use command line tools to save the first 1000 rows in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gregor Thomas' comment, `sep = "\t"` can be used to separate the data into different columns. I hope the following way can be one of possibly efficient ways to read `data1.csv`:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("data1.csv", sep = "\t") 
dat1 <- dat |> 
    apply(1,tstrsplit, split = ",") |> 
    do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _)|> 
    setNames(
       colnames(dat) |> 
       tstrsplit (split = "[,]")|> 
       unlist()
    )
    

dat1[,-1] <- apply(dat1[,-1], 2, as.numeric)
dat1
#  varA varB varC
#1  Id1    0   23
#2  Id2    1   34
#3  Id3    2  145

str(dat1)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ varA: chr  "Id1" "Id2" "Id3"
# $ varB: num  0 1 2
# $ varC: num  23 34 145
```

Comment: I got this error trying to run this code `Error in setnames(unlist(tstrsplit(colnames(dat), split = "[,]"))) : x is not a data.table or data.frame`

Comment: Oh OK I forgot this one. I have edited the code. Please kindly try it.